# python numpy convert string to complex number

Tags: python, numpy, complex-numbers

I have a list of strings, each of which is a complex number. The format is as below:

```
lr=['3.123+2.43i','0.23454-1.2134i','0.6543+0.76543i','1.12324+0.6543i']
```

What I want is a list of the modulus of each complex number.

Answer (score 6):

Python natively supports complex numbers, but it uses the engineering convention of *j* for the imaginary unit instead of the mathematician's *i*.

```
lr = ['3+4i', '3.123+2.43i', '0.23454-1.2134i', '0.6543+0.76543i', '1.12324+0.6543i']
for s in lr:
    s = s.replace('i', 'j')
    v = complex(s)
    print(v, abs(v))
```

**output**

```
(3+4j) 5.0
(3.123+2.43j) 3.9570227444380457
(0.23454-1.2134j) 1.2358594465391282
(0.6543+0.76543j) 1.006971486637035
(1.12324+0.6543j) 1.2999140693138143
```

We can create a list of the moduli using a list comprehension:

```
moduli = [abs(complex(s.replace('i', 'j'))) for s in lr]
print(moduli)
```

**output**

```
[5.0, 3.9570227444380457, 1.2358594465391282, 1.006971486637035, 1.2999140693138143]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a variation on the 'replace i with j' solution:

```
In [182]: lr=['3.123+2.43i','0.23454-1.2134i','0.6543+0.76543i','1.12324+0.6543i']
```

Can make an array of strings:

```
In [183]: np.array(lr)
Out[183]: 
array(['3.123+2.43i', '0.23454-1.2134i', '0.6543+0.76543i',
       '1.12324+0.6543i'], 
      dtype='<U15')
```

but not complex - at least not directly

```
In [184]: np.array(lr,np.complex)
...
TypeError: a float is required
```

but there is a function that performs string replace on array elements:

```
In [185]: a=np.array(lr)
In [186]: np.char.replace(a,'i','j')
Out[186]: 
array(['3.123+2.43j', '0.23454-1.2134j', '0.6543+0.76543j',
       '1.12324+0.6543j'], 
      dtype='<U15')
```

Now that array of strings can be cast as complex

```
In [187]: np.char.replace(a,'i','j').astype(np.complex)
Out[187]: 
array([ 3.12300+2.43j   ,  0.23454-1.2134j ,  0.65430+0.76543j,
        1.12324+0.6543j ])
```

Comment: This method doesn't work. It will get `TypeError: must be real number, not numpy.str_`.

Comment: @pe-perry, what are you talking about?  Ask your own question with your own data; don't tack a context-less comment onto an old answer!

Comment: sorry for not being clear. `TypeError: must be real number, not numpy.str_` will be obtained when running `np.char.replace(a,'i','j').astype(np.complex)`.

Comment: @pe-perry, I have no idea what your `a` looks like, so can't help.

Comment: Exactly the same code in your answer, I just copy and run. Same `lr` and `a` as yours. My numpy version is 1.18.3.

Comment: I need to see `np.char.replace(a,'i','j')` before I can suggest any fixes.

Comment: `np.char.replace(a,'i','j')` looks fine, the error comes from `.astype(np.complex)`