# string to complex matrix representation in python

Tags: python, string, matrix

I have the following example string:

`s ="1 1+i\n1-i 0"`

Now I have to turn this string into a complex matrix. I am aware of the np.matrix() function but it is not designed for a complex matrix. Maybe some of you can provide me some ideas of how I can go forward. I also tried to split at \n but then I have two arrays which contain exactly one element (1 1+i & 1-i 0 ). The result should be:
 `np.array([[1, complex(1,1)], [complex(1, -1), 0]])`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What should the matrix result be in this example? And do you mean that the string contains the literal characters `s` and `=`, or do you mean that you assigned the string to a variable like `s = "1 1+i\n1-i 0"`?

Comment: I assigned the string to a variable s. The result should be ```matrix = np.array([[1, complex(1,1)], 
              [complex(1, -1), 0]])```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show this. And also answer all my questions.

Comment: In python a string is surrounded by double or single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question has two parts.

First, we want to convert the string into a list of complex numbers (as strings), and then [convert this list into the actual complex numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40421736/14627505).

```py
s = "1 1+i\n1-i 0"

import re

complex_strings = re.split("\n|\s+", s.replace('i', 'j'))
complex_numbers = [complex(x) for x in complex_strings]
m = np.array(complex_numbers).reshape(2, 2)
```

```py
[[1.+0.j 1.+1.j]
 [1.-1.j 0.+0.j]]
```